# Displaying local html in iOS UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, ios

Ok I have looked thru the web and have had trouble understanding what other people were posting. I am new to Objective-C. All I want to do is use WebView to display a local html5 app.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *fullURL = @"http://fc-pc.com/AMG/index.html";
    //NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"www"]];
    [_viewWeb loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_viewWeb loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

Thats what I have at the moment. It will display html from a hosted site but not locally.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Why are you loading the URL twice? What happens? Have you verified that `url` isn't `nil`?

Comment: That was my fault I was trying the extra line and left it in there. I have been trying all sorts of load html lines.

Comment: What about my other questions?

Comment: it is null when it tries to load it locally, but not when using the website address

Comment: Are you sure index.html is in a folder named www in the deployed app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading from a website:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://fc-pc.com/AMG/index.html"];
[_viewWeb loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

`requestWithURL` requires a `NSURL` and you've used a `NSString` ([Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy))

Loading from your bundle:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO];
[_viewWeb loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

to load `index.html` stored in your main bundle. Oh and make sure you've added your html file to your project's resources bundle. If you've dragged the file into Xcode it may not have been added properly.

Comment: This works to load it from the website. So first I'll thank you for cleaning up my disaster. Now how would I load it locally. Do I need a special code or could a file:// work like in android?

Comment: Well I did initially give you the answer to that but you've edited your question for the third time. I've updated my answer to give you both methods.

Comment: That was my fault answering to another comment. I'm sorry about the confusion. It almost works. Here is my issue in my main it isn't returning the right item now. I have`        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    String* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```